# GameObject isn't in the hieararchy, but its script's Update is called?

Tags: unity-game-engine, invisible, gameobject

Now I am facing a ghost object.

There was a script attached to an object which I deleted. But for some reason, the script's update function is always being called.

I added this line to the Update: `Debug.Log(name)`, and its name is `Flamestrike`, but when I search it in the hierarchy, there are no results.

And if I set its position to `0,1,0` (so it should be visible), it is not visible in the game either.

So please help me because it drives me crazy :(

**Edit:**

```
Debug.Log("a");
if(transform.parent == null) {
    transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
    Debug.Log("Canvas");
}
```

I also tried this, and it prints Canvas, so **it sets its parent to Canvas**, but **I can't see any Flamestrike objects under Canvas**.

Comment: You should read the [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and make sure you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, I will work on that, sorry. But there are no scripts, which could cause this problem, because it can be instantiated by pushing a button, and I didn't edit anything there. 
I just deleted the object from the hierarchy, but for some reason it is not deleted.
 I remember that i deleted the object's child, but the the whole object got deleted. (it's a prefab)

Comment: How many times does it print "Canvas"?  If it's continuously then there is no game object called "Canvas".

Comment: Only once, white A is printed everytime the Update is called.

Comment: I'll help ya debug it, but it'd be easier if you can just chat with me. This isn't really the best questions for SO, do you have like gmail or something? Are you on the unity3D IRC? I'd say here but you don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I am very curious about it. Please post an answer when you find solution.

Comment: `Debug.Log(name);` will print the name of the script (i.e. `MonoBehaviour.name`), not the name of the `GameObject` it's attached to.  You want `Debug.Log(gameObject.name);` instead.

Comment: First I tried that, and it gave the same name (the object's name is equal to the script's name), but there is no object with that name.

Comment: I'm also tracking this question, please post the solution. @trojanfoe you can also search components in hierarchy.

Comment: Email sent bro, Let's get this figured out!

Comment: @Tudvari try searching MonoDevelop for all references of **Flamestrike**. hope it will get you somewhere

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but what do you mean by "search MonODevelep?"

Comment: Ok you're over 20 reputation now, and I haven't heard back on that email yet, so maybe come join me over in the unity chatroom? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102339/unity

Comment: no, I mean... [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) is a default coding IDE for Unity, but you may as well be using Visual Studio, or xCode or whatever. Anyways, in most IDE's hitting CTRL+SHIFT+F usually brings up a window to search keywords in all scripts. So look at all the places you use the **Flamestrike** classes, or objects, to see if you missed out something. In MonoDevelop you can also Right Click on **Flamestrike** in a script, then click on > Find All References.

Comment: @NikaKasradze I think he is Instantiating a prefab, and it is somehow getting hidden in the hiearchy. Not really sure why that would occur though.

Comment: Log more information about gameObject (like `gameObject.name`), List of attached `Components` it's position (`transform.position`). This my help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When Instantiating a prefab GameObject, for some reason it was being created with Hidden Flags. In order to solve this, we added the code: `this.gameObject.hideFlag = HideFlags.None;` which allowed the object to show up in the hiearchy finally.

The only other source I could find on this was this answer, which had basically no explanation as to why it occured. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/921819/instantiated-prefabs-not-showing-up-in-hierarchy.html (quoted below)

> Found the issue, not sure why but: These two ways are working (prefab
>   is a GameObject defined elsewhere).
>
> `Player1 = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;`
>
> `Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;`
>
> For some reason the prototype:
>
> `Instantiate(prefabName, position, rotation);`
>
> Was not working.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry if this is not the correct way to write this, but the comments are too short, and can't be formatted)

This not fully true, I think.

This hidden gameObject wasn't created via script. I dragged the prefab to the scene, then somehow I didn't delete the  prefab fully. (or didn't even delete, just made it hidden)

It disappeared in the hieararchy, but it wasn't deleted fully.
After we made the object visible via script, now it is visible. 
(but only in play mode, so I can't delete it, because it is not visible in scene view)

And it got some interesting components/attributes.
The original story:

FlameStrike - a Container for scaling purposes (empty gameObject)

-FlameStrike - a gameobject with animation, FlameStrike.cs script etc.

--Particle System - a part. system with this exact name.

But after we found the remaining hidden object it was like this:
[image]

So I don't understand what I did. It deleted some parts of the prefab, but also mixed some parts,

(like adding the Particle System object's Particle System component to this FlameStrike object)

then made it hidden. Is there a hotkey for this? :D Because it is not script related issue, I did this in the editor.

Comment: The prefab it is referencing does not exist, note how above transform it says "missing". Could you have deleted the prefab possibly?

Comment: Hm..  Possibly. I dragged the prefab to the scene, edited it, then deleted the prefab, and dragged the gameobject to the project folder, and made a new prefab.

Comment: I wrote in the chat room, I hope I don't disturb you :)

Comment: I'll be there shortly

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue:

- Enter play mode in editor
- Instantiate() an object
- set `instance.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSaveInBuild | HideFlags.DontSaveInEditor`
- Exit play mode
- Enter play mode again (don't do anything)

The old object is still having Update() called on it.

My fix was to not set those flags if `Application.isPlaying`